# How to redefine loaded classes from compiled classfiles

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to redefine an existing class (called Module) in my code with new versions during runtime. The new versions come in the form of compiled classfiles that are saved in some directory. Is there a way for me to do this with ByteBuddy?

I have tried to use the ByteArrayClassLoader to define a class from the classfile. The defined class seems to have the updated methods. I've checked this by going through the methods of the defined class and invoking them (i.e the `process` method which returns some String). However, when I try to use ByteBuddy.redefine(...), I get the error "Could not locate class file for some.package.Module" I tried passing in the ClassFileLocator I used to find the class file for the new version but I still get this error.

```java
    public void redefine() throws Exception {

        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/someDir";

        Map<String, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        ClassFileLocator cfl = new ForFolder(new File(path));
        byte[] clazzBytes = cfl.locate("Module").resolve();
        map.put(clazz.getName(), clazzBytes);

        ByteArrayClassLoader bac = new ByteArrayClassLoader(ClassLoadingStrategy.BOOTSTRAP_LOADER, false, map);

        Class<?> replacementClass = bac.defineClass(clazz.getName(), clazzBytes);

        for (Method m : replacementClass.getMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().equals("process")) {
                System.out.println((String) m.invoke(replacementClass.newInstance(), "invoked from new instance"));
            }
        }
        AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(new Listener.Filtering(
                new StringMatcher("bytebuddy_instrumentation.Module", Mode.CONTAINS),
                Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut()
            ))
            .with(RedefinitionStrategy.REDEFINITION)
            .with(Default.REDEFINE)
            .disableClassFormatChanges()
            .type(ElementMatchers.is(clazz))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
                new ByteBuddy()
                    .redefine(replacementClass, cfl)
                    .name(clazz.getName()));

        this.resetter = agentBuilder.installOnByteBuddyAgent();
    }
```

The redefinition fails with the current code due to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate class file for some.package.Module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to replace another class with another byte code representation, why would you want to use Byte Buddy?

You can replace a class with the `Instrumentation` API by using `redefineClass` where you can directly pass the replacement.

The error probably stems from your use of a `REDEFINE` strategy where Byte Buddy needs to locate the class files of all classes. It would probably be better to use `RETRANSFORM`. However, it is impossible to tell for sure without a stack trace.